# Test Dataflow with DirectRunner and got lots of verifyUnmodifiedThrowingCheckedExceptions

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I was testing my Dataflow pipeline using DirectRunner from my Mac and got lots of "WARNING" message like this, may I know how to get rid of them because it is too much that I can not even see my debug message.

Thanks

```
Apr 05, 2018 2:14:48 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MutationDetectors$CodedValueMutationDetector verifyUnmodifiedThrowingCheckedExceptions
WARNING: Coder of type class org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder has a #structuralValue method which does not return true when the encoding of the elements is equal. 
Element com.apigee.analytics.platform.core.service.schema.EventRow@4a590d0b
```

Answer (score 7):

It may help to ensure that all serialized values have proper `equals()` implementations since `SerializableCoder` [expects](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/SerializableCoder.java#L71) them:

> The structural value of the object is the object itself. The `SerializableCoder` should be only used for objects with a proper `Object#equals` implementation.

You can implement your own `Coder` for your POJOs. SerializableCoder does not guarantee a deterministic encoding according to [docs](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/SerializableCoder.java#L46):

> `SerializableCoder` does not guarantee a deterministic encoding, as Java
>   serialization may produce different binary encodings for two equivalent
>   objects.

[This article explains custom coders in details](http://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-beam/coders-apache-beam/read#coders_explained).

Comment: Do you have any examples or resources on how to implement a Coder? I'm struggling with this same exception and I can't seem to make heads or tails just from the javadoc for the [Coder](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/Coder.html)

Comment: @nomadic_squirrel I just added good article about custom coder to original answer.

Comment: I'm having these as well. Not sure what the resolution is - should I implement a custom coder?

Answer (score 2):

Just add
https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode

```
@EqualsAndHashCode 
public class YourRecord implements Serializable {
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I was using SerializableCoder for a class implementing Serializable, and my tests were failing because the PAssert() containsInAnyOrder() method was not using MyClass.equals() to evaluate object equality. The signature of my equals() method was:

```
public boolean equals(MyClass other) {...}
```

All I had to do to fix it was to define equals in terms of Object:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {...}
```

This made the warnings go away, and made the tests pass.